# The district function forms a metric space on X.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a non empty set and $d_0$ be a function such that $d_0(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d_0(x,y)=1$ o.w. show that $(X,d_0)$ is a metric space.
It is trivial to see why the three first conditions for a metric holds but I can't show why the triangular inequality holds.
Please any hints will be helpful. I just don't know how to start. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to prove $d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$, then consider cases. What happens when $x = y = z$? What happens when $x = y \neq z$? Is it any different to the $x \neq y = z$ case? What about when they're all different? What about when $x = z \neq y$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Ahhhh!I got it. Thank you.